Identifying Waveforms that Satisfy Specific Convolution Constraints
I am attempting to find a set of waveforms, denoted as $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$, that satisfy the following convolution constraints, where $*$ is used to denote a convolution:
$$
y_1,y_2,y_3 \text{ are distinct}.
$$
$$
\begin{split}
y_1 * y_2 &= y_2 * y_1 = y_3 \\
y_1 * y_3 &= y_3 * y_1 = y_2 \\
y_2 * y_3 &= y_3 * y_2 = y_1
\end{split}$$
Could someone help me determine what these waveforms $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$ could be given these constraints? Additionally, any insights into the properties or characteristics of these waveforms would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
The waveforms $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$ are assumed to be continuous functions.
There's a long and convoluted story for how I arrived at this problem but it's not really relevant, suffice it to say, I'm long out of school and have basically no background in understanding convolutions. I've learned from Google that if $\mathcal F$ is used to denote the Fourier transformation, then if $y_1$ is the convolution of $y_2$, and $y_3$, then $\mathcal F(y_1) = \mathcal F(y_2)\cdot \mathcal F(y_3)$, so that's neat. Otherwise it's been a long time since I've had to use waves for much and I've grown a bit rusty. That all said, is it possible to have a set of waveforms as outlined above? If so, are there other additional constraints they'd need to conform to or are there exact answers for what these waves might be? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Hm, assuming the Fourier transformation can be applied to the functions, the system of equation would be converted to multiplications like you said. But then it is not hard to conclude that $\mathcal F(y_i) = \pm 1$ for all three (they would be $1,1,1$ or $1,-1,-1$). I think this means that the original functions would be something like the Dirac delta distribution, but now I'm already out of my depth. Maybe there could also be solutions where the Fourier transform just doesn't apply

I edited the question to format the math properly. In future, please use MathJax to format all math.

@Milten Thank you for updating the formatting, I'll do better in the future. I can't say I entirely understand how convolutions work. I sent this to a friend whose somewhat well versed in math but also usually doesn't respond much and he sent back this $y_1(x) = e^{ix}$, $y_2(x) = e^{2ix}$, and $y_3(x) = e^{-3ix}$. Given my limited understanding, how would one ensure these hold to the constraints above?

From the definitions I know, the convolution of your friend's example would be either $y_1*y_2(t) = \int_{\Bbb R}e^{ix}e^{2i(t-x)}dx$, which is undefined, or  $\int_0
^{2\pi}e^{ix}e^{2i(t-x)}dx = 0$, so I don't see how it should work...

Suppose that their Fourier transforms exist, which we write as $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $Y_3$. Their products then must satisfy
$$
\begin{align}
Y_1 \circ Y_2 & = Y_3 \\
Y_1 \circ Y_3  & = Y_2 \\
Y_2 \circ Y_3 & = Y_1
\end{align}
$$
Substitute any one of these equations into one of the others and you will see that $Y_i(f) = \pm \sqrt{1}$. So for any frequency $f$, the function is either $+1$ or $-1$. If you define two of the waveforms in this manner, the third waveform is just the product of the two. You will then have three waveforms that satisfy your system of equations. The problem, however, is that I don't think these functions have an inverse Fourier transform.
If we wanted to only consider the sampled spectrum with $N$ discrete samples between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$, then we can define the waveforms randomly as in the following Matlab example:
% We could bandlimit these waveforms by zeroing some samples
% before IFFT'ing.
N = 1000;
y1 = ifft( (-1).^randi(2,[1000,1]) );
y2 = ifft( (-1).^randi(2,[1000,1]) );
y3 = ifft( fft(y1) .* fft(y2) );

These waveforms satisfy the equations but only for this specific set of time samples. If you were to actually generate these waveforms or shift them by half a sample, I would not expect their convolutions to satisfy the equations.

In a generalized sense, the inverse Fourier of $\pm 1$ is $\pm\delta$. But even if we allow these, we would have at least two of the three original waveforms equal.

@Milten My answer is not worded the best. If $Y_i(f) = +1$ or $Y_i(f) = -1$, then the inverse Fourier transform does exist in some type of non-finite energy sense (I forget the details). I was more thinking about the more general case where $Y_i(f) = \pm \sqrt{1}$, where, say, $Y_i(0) = +1$, but $Y_i(1) = -1$. On paper, these functions should satisfy the frequency domain constraints, but they are not realizable in the time domain.

@Milten A more specific example would be to let $Y_1(f) = +1$ for $f \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $Y_1(f) = -1$ for $f \notin \mathbb{Q}$. If we then define $Y_2(f)$ similarly but in the other direction such that $Y_2(f) = +1$ for $f \notin \mathbb{Q}$, and $Y_2(f) = -1$ for $f \in \mathbb{Q}$, we could compute $Y_3(f)$ such that the three equations are satisfied, but none of these "waveforms" have an inverse FT.

You are right of course! (I was somehow limiting myself to continuous Fourier functions). You missed a case though, that all three of the functions can be $0$ at a given point. So here is a candidate solution, where rect and sinc are defined as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms. The Fourier transformed functions could be $-rect(f/2), -rect(f/2)+2rect(f), rect(f/2)-2rect(f)$. Using the inverse transform we should get $-2sinc(2x), -2sinc(2x)+2sinc(x), 2sinc(2x)-2sinc(x)$. I might well have made an error here, but it should work in theory
